# Converting CGImageRef to NSData increase app memory usage in Mac app

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsdata, cgimageref

I am creating a mac app in which I am converting the CGImageRef to NSData and then Base64 and sending on a server.

This thing happens in Loop, and every time image converted in NSData app memory usage increase.

Here is my code

```
CGImageRef screenShot = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectInfinite, kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID, kCGWindowImageDefault);
bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage: screenShot];


NSData *imageData = [bitmapRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];;
NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Please let me know if I am doing any mistake,
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `CGImageRelease(screenShot)`? I think it should help. Call it when you're done. Seems like you're not releasing the memory that you have received with `CGWindowListCreateImage`

Comment: I'll add this: Old "stuff", struct like usually with a `Ref` suffix need to be manually release (no ARC). Usually, each have a specific Release method, `CGImageRelease()` in your case, that can be found on the the same level of the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage?language=objc